# 301 redirect from dynamic URL in subfolder to a new static URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I reviewed all the different solutions for redirecting dynamic URLs to a static URL but I couldn't find any case related with my question.

I would like to know what should be the correct 301 redirect rule for .htaccess

Additional info:

- The old URLs were deleted after launching the new site.
- The Old URLs are located in a subfolder (/desarrollo/mantenedores/)
- "art_id" is the string and the "61" is the article

Here is the case I want to redirect OLD Dynamic URLs to their individual static URLs.

Old URL = http://example.com/desarrollo/mantenedores/art_indice.asp?art_id=61

New URL = http://example.com/comunidad/articles/2/tipos-de-sociedades

Thanks...

Comment: pedrohd - I cannot see how the old urls are related to the new ones e.g what in the old url made you choose articles/2/tipos-de-sociedades in the new url?

Comment: Hello Ulrich Palha.. the old URLs were part of the old site (asp framework) that was migrated to a new framework (php).. Nothing is related in terms of the url name( just the content that was migrated) that is why I need to do permanent redirect on those old urls that are returning not found.. thank you for your help-- pedrohd

Comment: Roughly how many urls are there to redirect: 10, 1000, 10,000?

Comment: For that many, RewriteMap below is the way to go.

Comment: working on and will let you know the results.. thank you both

Answer (score 1):

Please try to fill a rewritemap file (see [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap)) to make a correspondance with the URL destination.

Create a mapfile where you put all the categories you need:

```
RewriteMap mapoldtonew \
  dbm:/web/htdocs/yoursite/rewriterules/mapoldtonew.map
```

Regarding your sample, your map file may be filled with things like:

```
art_id=61        articles/2/tipos-de-sociedades
...
```

Then here you go for the hard part:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} desarrollo/(.*)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (([^=]+)=([0-9]+))
# The following rule doesn't touch the URL, but 
# will try to search into the map file and
# create an OLDTONEW environment variable with the string found
# and if not found, assign OLDTONEW to "notfound"
RewriteRule . - [QSA,E=OLDTONEW:${mapoldtonew:%1|notfound}]

# if the OLDTONEW is not empty and is not found:
RewriteCond %{ENV:OLDTONEW} notfound
# this should never happen => 404:
RewriteRule . - [R=404,L]

# Reach here means :
# - OLDTONEW is empty
# - OLDTONEW is was found
# => if OLDTONEW is not empty:
RewriteCond %{ENV:OLDTONEW} !^$
# make the redirection to the corresponding found:
RewriteRule . /%{ENV:CATEGORYREVERSE} [QSA,L]
```

This should work.
If it doesn't try to change `%1` to `%2` in the *first* RewriteRule directive.
If it still doesn't you may have enough clues to finish the job.
If you don't have enough clues...

### Two hints:

---

Please try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

Comment: Hello all, bad news I got an Internal Server Error I tried both options %1 and %2
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
Apache mod_qos/9.69 mod_fcgid/2.3.6 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 Server at www.mysite.com Port 80